# how to string (html) convert to pdf file and send API in android

Tags: android, pdf

I have a html string.I want to convert  string to pdf file and try to post.Function not return File.How to resolve this issue.

```
public static void pdf (String html) {

    // step 4
    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        // step 2
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("test.pdf"));
        // step 3
        document.open();
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
                in);
        document.close();
        Log.e("test",  "PDF Created!" );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you know that it `not return File`? have you checked?

Comment: @Vlad Matvienko   yes

Comment: and what? how have you checked it? since return type is `void`, it won't return anything in any case.

Comment: This piece of code will definitely throw two compilation errors. You have used colon after `return document:` which should be a semicolon `return document;` and another is misplaced/ missing return statement. Please check your code first.

Comment: how to return pdf File ?

Comment: I do not know how return pdf File.

Comment: You probably mean that you want to let your pdf() function return a File object. Well then you should have a File object in your function. Which you have not. Probably you want the File object to point to the just created file. You have not made such an object.

Comment: `new FileOutputStream("test.pdf")`. Bad idea to provide a file name only. Have you any idea where the file will be saved? You better provide a full path. Use the File class to build up a full path first. Then open a file output stream. The nice thing is that you also have a File object then which you can return.

Comment: @greenapps Full path without mentioning I can not return?

Comment: I don't want to save the file i created in the phone memory. I want to create and send file... Possible?

Comment: Use the OutputStream of the http connection instead of a FileOutputStream.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134748/discussion-between---and-greenapps).